# How to display Multiple iframes of same domain on a single html page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i have a html page with multiple iframes in it all from the same domain with different urls

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>testing</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>TEst 1 </h1>
<iframe src="http://example.com?id=123" id="app"  width="100%" height="388" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<h1>TEst 2 </h1>
<iframe src="http://example.com?id=456" id="app"  width="100%" height="388" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

but while running the both iframes render the same page either the first one twice or the second one twice. 
they both work perfectly if used alone but why are they overwriting each other?

Comment: ID's must be unique, maybe it's not the cause, but you should fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were nothing wrong with my code. It should work even with the same id.
**The problem however was with the website. The website doesn't support multiple versions of itself in the same page.** 
Thanks for the answers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. Here is an example of using your code, just replaced you dummy src URLs with youtube videos.

https://jsfiddle.net/6gp1gyps/

```
<h1>TEst 1 </h1>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UbB_NkQrDr4" id="app"  width="100%" height="388" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<h1>TEst 2 </h1>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jiFDY6N33aw" id="app"  width="100%" height="388" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

You can have same ID for both if you do not use the IDs for other control.

Answer (score 0):

You should set different ids;

```
<h1>TEst 1 </h1>
<iframe src="http://example.com?id=123" id="app"  width="100%" height="388" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<h1>TEst 2 </h1>
<iframe src="http://example.com?id=456" id="app2"  width="100%" height="388" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unique Id's:

Working code:

```
<iframe id="app1" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0px; height:1222px; width:100%;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XYviM5xevC8"></iframe>
    <iframe id="app2" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0px; height:1222px; width:100%;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jiFDY6N33aw"></iframe>
```

Follow this :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: i tried using unique ids , unique name attribute , nothing works. i wrote them in html file and open it in chrome doesnt work. Any idea why ?

Comment: @amitavamozumder i think class and styles are overridding. Try this one. I have added img. You add your src (Youtube video) to display.   
 <div class="card">
 <div class="card card-body card-padding">
  <div class="row">
   <iframe id="app1" src="bg1.jpg"></iframe>
   <iframe id="app2" src="Bg2.jpg"></iframe>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>  Note:Remove style in my previous answer.Use bootstrap cdn in your file.

Comment: It's working. I have checked in my machine. Check it in your side as well.Let me know if it works.